# Flask-WTF FieldList issue: more instances than required

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm new using Flask and html but doing so research I found multiple possible solutions, however I'm still having errors.

I'm working on a page where an admin user will provide access to new users which already send a request. After the possible users submit their request, it will be uploaded to the access_request_table. I'm displaying all the applications in a table, which uses FieldList for each row based on that the whole page is my only form. I wanted to do this so I could delete this rows from my access_request_table and send them to the users_table, however, as you will see the length of the FieldList and the number of rows is different.

The page works, and displays the way that I want, however, when I manually input data into the form and click on the submit button, it adds more entries to the FieldList than the ones that should. I've tried multiple times and ways to make it run but it won't do it properly.
For example here, the table have 2 rows so I should expect that my FieldList would have only 2 inputs, but it had 4. So as you can see I'm not able to validate my form and not printing the test statement.

The table is displayed here: [example of table rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw3Rb.png)

This are the outputs that I have when I click on submit:

```
{  'rows': [
       {'id': '', 'access': 'Yes', 'comment': ''}, 
       {'id': '', 'access': 'No', 'comment': ''}, 
       {'id': None, 'access': '', 'comment': None}, 
       {'id': None, 'access': '', 'comment': None}
   ], 
   'submit': True, 'csrf_token': 'ImFhMDg0YTM3N2YxYWY4OTkwODQwZDY1Y2FhYjNhYWI1ZThjN2MxOTQi.YSbbMQ.OjHsnnYZTjjh308FLuqR6zekMEY'
}

rerender
```

This is my forms.py:

```
class AccessRow(Form):
    # The HiddenField later contains the id of the data record. 
    id = HiddenField('id')
    access = SelectField('access', validators=[DataRequired()], choices=[('','Please Select...'),('Yes','True'),('No','False')], default='',coerce=str)
    comment = StringField('comments')

    # The constructor is overwritten in order to bypass further fields for the csrf token. 
    def __init__(self, csrf_enabled=False, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AccessRow, self).__init__(csrf_enabled=csrf_enabled, *args, **kwargs)

class AccessForm(FlaskForm):
    rows = FieldList(FormField(AccessRow),validators=[Required()])  
    submit = SubmitField('Update')
```

This is my routes.py, currently I muted the redirection to know if everything was validated and correct.

```
@app.route("/home/admin", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home_admin():
    requests = RequestAccess.query.all()
    form = AccessForm()
    for request in requests:
        form.rows.append_entry()

    if form.is_submitted():   
        print(form.data)

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print('test')
      #  return redirect(url_for('about'))
    print('rerender')
    return render_template("admin_access_approval.html", title="Admin Access Approval", form=form, requests=requests, range=range(rows))
```

Finally this is my html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div id="example_wrapper-2" class="dataTables_wrapper" >
    <form id="basicForm" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        
        <h2 class="h3">Access requests Table</h2>  
        <table id="dataTableExample" class="table table-striped" style="width:100%"> 
            <caption class="sr-only">Employee List</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr><th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Last name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Work Type</th>
                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                        <th scope="col">Access</th>
                        <th scope="col">Comments</th>
                        <td></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {%for row, request, ii in zip(form.rows, requests,range)%}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{request.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{request.lastname}}</td>
                        <td>{{request.workdesc}}</td>
                        <td>{{request.email}}</td>
                        <td>{{row.access(class="custom-select")}}</td>
                        <td>{{row.comment(class="form-control", value ='')}}</td>
                    </tr>
                {%endfor%}
                <tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-primary mt-2", value = "Submit Changes") }}
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{%endblock content%}
```

I've been trying many ideas but I was not able to make it work, I would appreciate your help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your user first visits the page (GET request), logic goes through `home_admin()` and through the `for` loop appending 2 rows to the form.  These are rendered on the page.  User clicks submit (POST request).  Logic goes back through `home_admin()` this time with 2 rows already in the form (with values the user entered).  Then it hits the `for` loop again and adds 2 empty rows for a total of 4.

You can quick fix by moving the `for` loop after the 2 `if` statements.  If there's other logic to be built in it might be more straightforward to nest the differing GET/POST logic in `if request.method == 'GET':` and `elif request.method == 'POST':`.